# What is Python's *Args and **kwargs equivalent in Rust

Tags: rust, keyword-argument

What is Python's *Args and **kwargs equivalent in Rust

```
def main(*args, **kwargs):
  pass
```

Comment: Rust doesn't have variadic functions, if that is what you mean.

Comment: `let args: Vec<String> = std::env::args().collect();` -- from https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-01-accepting-command-line-arguments.html

Comment: We generally [don't do code translation here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265825/). Rather than ask for an equivalent to something from another language, use English to explain directly what the code needs to do. That way, the Rust experts (who are the correct people to answer your question) don't also have to know any Python in order to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [variadic arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) and Rust has no direct equivalent. This is because Rust is [extremely strongly typed](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html) and must know exactly what types will be passed to a function.

Depending on what you're doing, you'd probably define a function that takes [collections](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/index.html); `Vec` for `*args` and `HashMap` for `**kwargs`. But everything in each collection must be of the same type; a Vec of integers, a HashMap of pairs of strings, etc.

Comment: It's probably best to recommend accepting a `&[T]` reference slice instead of `Vec` directly.

Comment: @PitaJ Would you write that up as an answer, please? I'm not experienced in Rust.

Comment: @PitaJ I think that's needlessly nitpicky for this kind of answer, though a more complete and nuanced answer may say: `*args` could be a `Vec<T>`, a `&[T]`, or maybe a `Iterator<Item = T>`, or even a generic type depending on how its used in the equivalent Python. Ownership, structure, and behavior are all more explicit in Rust. Same goes for `**kwargs`.

Comment: Variadic arguments is _not_ antithetical to strong typing. It's either lower priority, or harder to get right. For example, variadic functions have been [implemented in Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-printf-0.1.0.0#readme) in a regular _library_, rather than as a language feature --- and Haskell makes similarly strong type safety guarantees. Rust is a bit less flexible than Haskell, so I can't say whether this library is portable to Rust or not. However, I can say with confidence that it's very hairy to read and understand how they did it. The types are just _magical_.

Comment: For Haskell, it basically boils down to predicting whether you have all the arguments you need, and returning a closure if you don't. Haskell's syntax for function application makes this work (allowing you to gobble up an arbitrary number of trailing expressions as arguments), so it probably would not be portable to Rust.

Comment: At the type level, it works by causing your intermediate closures to all implement the same trait as all of your eventual result values.